# AjaxControlToolkit combobox with datasource wont accept keyboard input

Tags: combobox, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Im trying to use the AjaxControlToolkit combobox with an sqldatasource in Listbox mode with suggest append. i have found that in listbox mode it is not possible to type in the box until either you enter then exit the textbox, or you click the dropdown arrow. I cant find a solution for this online. has anybody else experienced this problem and know a solution?

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your Page_Load event to instantiate your combobox to the first index

```
ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```